# Using Netty as a HTML server like Play

Tags: servlets, playframework, netty

Want to wrap my Spring services with RestEasy and hook the RestEasy dispatcher into Netty (there is a nice helper class called NettyJaxrsServer, just adds the RestEasy encodes/decoders into the pipeline).  That gets me going for client Ajax calls.  But what about serving up HTML content like is normally done through Apache or Tomcat.  Seen that people front Netty with Apache/Tomcat to get all the goodies of cookie management and so forth.  Took a brief look at the Play module for Netty which looks like it does so cookie management, caching, file chunking etc.  How comprehensive is Play's module?

Just browsing around for what others are doing.  In the end I want to push out a set of static HTML, JS, CSS content part of the Extjs or Foundation frameworks while Netty handling the "service" calls.

Comment: If you just need to serve static files via HTTP, have a look at [this example from netty.io](http://static.netty.io/3.5/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/http/file/package-summary.html).

Comment: Great link.  Basically the Play module does the same thing which was exactly what I needed to see.  Play adds a bunch of features for caching.

Comment: Xitrum may be suitable because it serves static files very fast and has features similar to those of RestEasy: http://ngocdaothanh.github.com/xitrum/